# What is the difference between Intent vs intent?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-intent

this is the code:

`override fun itemClicked(id: Long) {
        val intent = Intent(this, DetailActivity::class.java)
        intent.putExtra(DetailActivity.EXTRA_ID, id.toInt())
        startActivity(intent)
    }`

And now i know this is the explicit intent and i can call with it activity and pass some data. But there is this intent:

`intent.putExtra(DetailActivity.EXTRA_ID, id.toInt())
startActivity(intent)`

In Android Studio i get tool tip like that "intent" is from getIntent/setIntent . Can someone explain to me little further about this or some links if you understand me what i am trying to ask .

Thank you.

Comment: intent is a variable/instance name of class Intent,

Comment: You just need to read basics first.

Comment: just a  variable of Intent. Just take a look [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-filters) and here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Activity` has `getIntent`/`setIntent` methods, and such methods (with "get" and "set" in names in java) are represented as properties in kotlin. When you created a variable with the same name, you shadowed this "property". https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/java-interop.html#getters-and-setters

Answer (score 0):

**Intent** is the name of the class, and **intent** is variable, its name can be **i** also., intent is just name that you've given to your variable.

```
        val i = Intent(this, DetailActivity::class.java)
        i.putExtra(DetailActivity.EXTRA_ID, id.toInt())
        startActivity(i)
```

So in the above there is no **intent**, but still the code will work, so intent is just name of variable, here you can put any name you want.